# display checked in react

Tags: reactjs, checked

I'm trying to display  add checked to input when i is equal to zero

I have a checked state which is a boolean
so I should get checked= true and then checked= false

```
   lists.map( ( {  names = '' }, i ) => {
                            if(i === 0) {
                              setAttributes({checked : true});
                            }else{setAttributes({checked : false});}
                            return  <Fragment>
                                    <input className="noms" type="radio" id={ i } checked={checked}/>
```

but how could I get checked="checked" and then nothing like 
this

```
 <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
 <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked="checked"> I have a car<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need inside your Fragment:

`<input className="noms" type="radio" id={i} checked={checked ? checked : false}/>`

You don't really need a string value for the `checked` parameter. I always use a boolean, like this:

`<input className="noms" type="radio" id={i} checked={!!checked}/>`

Why `!!`? It will turn any *truthy* values to boolean `true` and any *falsy* values to boolean `false`.

Also, you probably need a `value` prop somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<input className="noms" type="radio" id={ i } {checked ? 'checked="checked"' : '' />
```

This evaluates your Boolean variable, and then outputs the string `checked="checked"` if checked is true, or the empty string if it's false.  The `BooleanExpression ? ifTrue : ifFalse` pattern is called a **[ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)**.